# Is there any Graphic tool to Localize strings in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, localization

[genstrings](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/genstrings.1.html) is a mess, diffstrings from facebook is a bit better but still. I can't find a great tool to localize iPhone Objective-C programs! Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't do localization myself, but there are a few [Apple developer tools](http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/localization/) that are for this intended purpose, including AppleGlot. I've also heard of [Loc-Suite](http://www.loc-suite.org/), [iLocalize](http://www.arizona-software.ch/ilocalize/), and [Polyglot](http://www.sticksoftware.com/software/Polyglot.html). You may wish to read Wil Shipley's post on localization, called ["Lost In Translations"](http://wilshipley.com/blog/2009/10/pimp-my-code-part-17-lost-in.html), and perhaps [this blog post](http://balthamos.blogspot.com/2008/05/introduction-so-you-are-probably-here_01.html) and [this screencast tutorial](http://www.equeltech.com/archives/140) as well. [CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?LocalizationTips) is always good to consult, too.

Comment: Loc-Suite mentioned in answer is great. worth trying out.

Comment: I know this is an old post but in case anyone runs across this like I did, there is now a great tool called Linguan made just for this purpose: https://www.cocoanetics.com/apps/linguan/

Answer (score 0):

I just create a graphical localization tool, but it's still in review, will be available in Mac App Store, you can watch the video here: [Localization Helper Video](http://bit.ly/gzxCo2)